# Java: I want to read from a file, character by character, and save each char into an array that has a max size of 10

Tags: java, filereader

this is my code:

```
    //array way
    char [] name = new char[10];

    while(input.hasNextLine()){
        firstName = input.next();

        for(int j = 0; j < name.length(); j++){
            name [j] = name.charAt(j);
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < name.length; i++){
                System.out.println(name);                
        }
    }
```

my inFile is in this format (name, social security number, then 4 grades):

```
SMITH 111112222 60.5 90.0 75.8 86.0
```

i have the variables initialized already, so thats not the problem. the overall goal for the name part is to read the file character by character, and save each char into an array with a max size of 10 (ie. only the first 10 letters of the name get saved). then i want to print that array.

the output is:
prints out SMITH 10 times, then the SSN 10 times, then instead of erasing the SSN, it overwrites the first 4 characters and replaces them with the grade

```
60.512222
```

and does that 10 times and so on. i dont know why it does this or how to fix it. can someone help plz?

ps. this is my first post here. plz tell me if im not posting efficiently

Comment: I'm pretty sure this won't compile. I don't think a char array has a `charAt` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try some thing like this (explanation inline):

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    while(input.hasNextLine()){
       //all variables are declared as local in the loop

        char [] name = new char[10];
        //read the name
        String firstName = input.next();

        //create the char array
        for(int j = 0; j < firstName.length(); j++){
            name [j] = firstName.charAt(j);
        }

       //print the char array(each char in new line)
        for(int i = 0; i < name.length; i++){
                System.out.println(name);                
        }

       //read and print ssn
        long ssn = input.nextLong();
        System.out.println(ssn); 


       //read and print grades
        double[] grades = new double[4];
        grades[0]= input.nextDouble();
        System.out.println(grades[0]); 
        grades[1]= input.nextDouble();
        System.out.println(grades[1]); 
        grades[2]= input.nextDouble();
        System.out.println(grades[2]); 
        grades[3]= input.nextDouble();
        System.out.println(grades[3]); 

        //ignore the new line char
        input.nextLine();
}

    //close your input stream
    input.close();
```

Comment: dude, that worked almost like a charm. and thank you for the intext comments, those are invaluable as well. and i was amazed at how fast i got these many responses. thanks everyone for the help

Answer (score 0):

here is an example which should work

```
try {

            FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("example.txt");
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            String strLine;
            char[] name = new char[10];
            while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                //save first 10 chars to name
                for (int i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
                    name[i]=strLine.charAt(i);
                }
                //print the current data in name
                System.out.println(name.toString());
            }
            in.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

You will need to reinitialize your array on each itertion of the loop because it is preserving the previous values:

```
name = new char[10];
```

Comment: Updated to reflect this. The issue is the same.